# Image in button with drawableTop can not be resized

Tags: android, image, button, resize

I am having a simple dashboard layout with several `Button`'s that show image and text.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/some_id"
        style="@style/DashboardButton"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/image"
        android:text="@string/text" />

<style name="DashboardButton">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

However, I can't seem to influence the size of the image by modifying `layout_width` or `layout_height`. I need the images to be bigger on tablets, now they are too small there.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: Do you have different images for different screen resolutions? I.e. drawable-xhdpi and drawable-hdpi, etc?

Comment: Hi, yes I have. I now resorted to using a `drawable-large-hdpi` folder with images that are scaled 150% in comparison with normal `hdpi`